# What is the difference between malloc and malloc(3)?

Tags: c, manpage

While reading a [hacker article](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=68&id=10) on the jemalloc memory manager, the hacker keeps referring to malloc(3), not malloc. I wondered why.

Does he do so because it refers to a specific linux malloc implementation? Or simply to refer to all malloc variants, that implement the interface as described on the [section 3 (libary functions)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) of the unix/linux manual pages? This option is my guess, want to be sure. Is there a different reason?

So, is the hacker just overly specific? Or is there a difference between malloc and malloc(3)?

The (3) part is not a reference to other documentation, article or research mentioned later in the hacker article.

Comment: Some people write(2) that way all the time(2), as it makes it clear(1)er what they are trying to stat(2)e.

Comment: The answers explain what the `3` means, but I do wonder _why_ people do it. Anyone interested in memory managers knows what malloc is, and anyone who does not know what malloc is will likely not understand what the `3` means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`malloc(3)` is just a hint that `malloc` is a part of the section 3 of the man pages. The section 3 is where are the library functions. This is by opposition to the section 2 of the man pages where are the syscalls. There is no `malloc(2)`.

For example:

`fwrite` is a library function so sometimes written as `fwrite(3)`

`write` is a syscall so sometimes written as `write(2)`

If you run the command:

```
$ man man
```

it will tell you

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages and convenâ
       tions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Answer (score 3):

Preface: My unix is weak.

I believe that it is simply a reference to the section 3 library.

( from the jargon file )
References such as malloc(3) and patch(1) are to Unix facilities (some of which, such as patch(1), are actually open source distributed over Usenet).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the author is simply being very specific.

Specifying the reference to section 3 of the man pages is often useful if there might be an e.g.  shell version of the same function. For instance, `man 1 printf` for printf(1) vs. printf(3).

But in the case of `malloc` documentation should exist only in section 3.

Comment: I believe he is referring to the POSIX definition of malloc. It's not just Linux specific.